# C++ template: retain non-type value info without store in the constructor

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have following template class:

```
template<unsigned char I, unsigned char F>
class FOO
{
  ....
}
```

In the main function, I have many such variables, with different (I, F), like following,

```
int main()
{
   .....
   FOO<4, 2> a;
   FOO<6, 3> b;
   ......
}
```

I want to retain the value of I or F for the defined variables in my main function. Of course, I can define a public/private members for FOO and save the value of (I, F) inside the FOO's constructor, like

```
template<I,F>
FOO<I,F>::FOO(){
   i = I;
   f = F;
}
```

Disadvantage of this method is obvious: It enlarge the size of the FOO. IMO, (I, F) of any variable can be determined at compiling time, so there should be a way to do this without creating local variable.

Comment: What about static const members in the template class? `static const unsigned char my_I = I;` Or via any kind of function in the class, static or non-static. If you think that won't work for you, I'm afraid you'll have to say how you actually plan to use the values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  You can use `I` or `F` anywhere inside your class template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way (like std::array in C++11) is to do the following:

```
constexpr unsigned char i() const { return I; }
constexpr unsigned char f() const { return F; }
```

If your compiler doesn't support constexpr, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Within your class definition, you can simply refer to the parameters literally (just like any other template parameters!).

But suppose you have this:

```
typedef Foo<10, 20> MyFoo;

MyFoo x;   // what is I, what is K?
```

The customary thing is to reflect the template parameters inside the class definition:

```
template <int A, typename T> struct Foo
{
    static int const a_value = A;
    typedef T               type;
    // ...
};
```

Now you can say: `MyFoo::type x; return MyFoo::a_value;` etc. Note that integral static class constants don't usually need a *definition* unless you do something like take their address, so in most cases this won't have *any* cost in the compiled code -- the compiler simply substitutes the value whenever it sees the name of the constant.

Answer (score 1):

you can *simply use* the **template parameters**, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<unsigned char I, unsigned char F>
class FOO
{
public:
    void bar() {
        cout << "I is: "<<I<<endl;
    }
    char getI() {
        return I;
    }
};

using namespace std;
int main(){
    FOO<4,2> a;
    a.bar();
    cout << "getI:"<<a.getI()<<endl;
}
```

you don't need a copy, as in your example (`i = I`)

BTW: fully capitalized names like *FOO* are usually by convention reserved for preprocessor Macros.